# Retrieve SQL View Column Metadata with Custom Query

Tags: sql, view, metadata

I created a SQL View and one of the column value is a SQL query for example 'SELECT TOP 1 value from TableB' with the column alias as 'Result'

I tried INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and the COLUMN_NAME only shown 'TableB'. How can I retrieve the 'SELECT TOP 1 value from TableB'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IronManWK
I found something for you. You should try this :

```
SELECT  M.definition  
FROM    sys.sql_modules M
WHERE   M.object_id = (SELECT V.object_id FROM sys.views V WHERE V.name = 'vue_2')
```

Reminder, `'vue_2'` is into my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used SQL SERVER 2012

```
create table A (
  id int identity(1,1), 
  data nvarchar(255),
)
;
INSERT A (data)
values ('A_ligne1'),('A_ligne2')

create table B (
  id int identity(1,10), 
  data nvarchar(255),
  date datetime default GetDate(),
)
;
INSERT B (data)
values ('B_ligne1'),('B_ligne2'),('B_ligne3'),('B_ligne4')
;
GO
CREATE VIEW vue_2 
AS 
SELECT A.*, (SELECT TOP 1 date FROM B) AS result
  FROM A 
;
```

When I make

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'vue_2'
```

the result set is

TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME

- vue_2       id
- vue_2       data
- vue_2       result

So, where is your problem ?

Comment: Based on the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS query, I'm looking for the column to show '(SELECT TOP 1 date FROM B)' instead of 'result' in COLUMN_NAME column